# Do the coefficients of the weight enumerator polynomial add up to $2^{n-k}$ for any $[\![n,k]\!]$ code?

Tags: error-correction

Let $ C $ be an $ [\![n,k]\!] $ quantum error correcting code encoding $ k $ logical qubits into $ n $ physical qubits. Define the weight enumerator polynomial $ A(x) $ of the code as
$$
A(x):=A_0+A_1x+\dots+A_nx^n
$$
where
$$
A_j:=\frac{1}{(2^k)^2} \sum_{p \in P_n,\,\mathrm{wt}(p)=j} |\mathrm{tr}(p \Pi)|^2.
$$
here $ \Pi $ is the projector onto the code space.
Is it the case that
$$
A(1)=A_0+A_1+\dots +A_n=2^{n-k}
$$
for an arbitrary $ [\![n,k]\!] $ code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the case that $\sum_{i=0}^nA_i=2^{n-k}$ for any $[\![n,k]\!]$ quantum error correcting code. To see this, begin by expanding the code subspace projector $\Pi$ in the Pauli basis and calculate
$$
\begin{align}
\Pi &= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{p\in P_n}\mathrm{tr}(p\Pi)p\tag1\\
\Pi &= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{p\in P_n}\mathrm{tr}(p\Pi)p\Pi\tag2\\
\mathrm{tr}(\Pi) &= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{p\in P_n}\mathrm{tr}(p\Pi)^2\tag3\\
2^k&= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{p\in P_n,\mathrm{wt}(p)=i}\mathrm{tr}(p\Pi)^2\tag4\\
2^{-k}&= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(2^k)^2}\sum_{p\in P_n,\mathrm{wt}(p)=i}\mathrm{tr}(p\Pi)^2\tag5\\
2^{-k}&= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^nA_i\tag6\\
2^{n-k}&= \sum_{i=0}^nA_i\tag7\\
\end{align}
$$
as expected.

Comment: Nice alternative proof given here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/30187/19675

Comment: Actually the link is only a valid alternative proof for the case of stabilizer codes. The answer above is more general since it gives a proof valid for all codes.