# Are the coefficients of the weight enumerator polynomial of a stabilizer code always integers?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Consider an $ [\![n,k]\!] $ stabilizer code. Define the weight enumerator polynomial $ A(x) $ of the code as
$$
A(x):=A_0+A_1x+\dots+A_nx^n
$$
where
$$
A_j:=\frac{1}{(2^k)^2} \sum_{p \in P_n,\,\mathrm{wt}(p)=j} |\mathrm{tr}(p \Pi)|^2.
$$
Here $ \Pi $ is the projector onto the code subspace.
Is it the case that the $ A_j $ are always integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** For the stabilizer codes, $A_j$ is the number of stabilizer operators with Hamming weight $j$ and thus a non-negative integer.

---

Suppose $g_1,\dots,g_{n-k}$ are generators of the stabilizer group $S$ of a $[\![n,k]\!]$ stabilizer code. Define $S^w:=\{s\in S\,|\,\mathrm{wt}(s)=w\}$ and $P_n^w:=\{p\in P_n\,|\,\mathrm{wt}(p)=w\}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
A_j &= \frac{1}{4^k}\sum_{p\in P_n^j}[\mathrm{tr}(p\Pi)]^2\tag1\\
&= \frac{1}{4^k}\sum_{p\in P_n^j}\left[\mathrm{tr}\left(p\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac{I+g_i}{2}\right)\right]^2\tag2\\
&= \frac{1}{4^k}\sum_{p\in P_n^j}\left[\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\mathrm{tr}\left(p\sum_{b_1=0}^1\dots\sum_{b_{n-k}=0}^1g_1^{b_1}\dots g_{n-k}^{b_{n-k}}\right)\right]^2\tag3\\
&= \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{p\in P_n^j}\left[\mathrm{tr}\left(p\sum_{s\in S}s\right)\right]^2\tag4\\
&= \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{p\in P_n^j}\left(\sum_{s\in S}\mathrm{tr}(ps)\right)^2\tag5\\
&= \frac{1}{4^n}\left[\sum_{p\in P_n^j\setminus S}\left(\sum_{s\in S}\mathrm{tr}\left(ps\right)\right)^2+\sum_{p\in S^j}\left(\sum_{s\in S}\mathrm{tr}\left(ps\right)\right)^2\right]\tag6\\
&= \frac{1}{4^n}\left(0+\sum_{p\in S^j}\left(2^n\right)^2\right)\tag7\\
&=|S_j|\tag8
\end{align}
$$
in analogy with the classical case. This gives us another way to see [that](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/30181/10480) $A_0+\dots+A_n=2^{n-k}=|S|$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on whether the $ A_j $ are always integers for non stabilizer codes? If you want I can accept this answer and make a different question specifically for non-stabilizer codes.

Comment: This is such a nice answer I'll edit my question to specifically be about stabilizer codes and just accept this answer

Comment: Would you happen to know a reference for this?  Especially one that might contain the corresponding result "For stabilizer codes, $ B_j $
 is the number of pauli operators in the normalizer $ N(S) $ with Hamming weight $ j $
 and thus a non-negative integer."

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a reference for a similar result for $B_j$ (nor for $A_j$ for that matter), but I expect a similar technique as in this answer to work for $B_j$, too.