# Codes with codewords that aren't uniform modulus superposition

Tags: error-correction, mathematics, stabilizer-code, stabilizer-state

All stabilizer codes and also all non stabilizer codes that I am aware of, for example the ones here,

[Example non-stabilizer code?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27610/example-non-stabilizer-code)

have a basis of codewords which are all uniform modulus superpositions of computational basis kets, in the sense that every nonzero coefficient has modulus
$$
1/\sqrt{|S|}
$$
where $ |S| $ is the size of the support of the codeword.

In the particular case of stabilizer codes every nonzero coefficient has modulus
$$
1/\sqrt{2^r}
$$
for some fixed $ r \leq n-k $. For a reference see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27573/19675

What is an example of a (necessarily non-stabilizer) code for which the code space is not spanned by codewords which are all uniform modulus superpositions?

So to reiterate I'm looking for a $ d=2 $ code for which the code space is not spanned by codewords which are all uniform modulus superpositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we’re leaving stabilizer codes behind, let’s go even farther away: [spin codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.10910) are one example.

Comment: Do non-uniform superpositions of (stabilizer) codewords count? Because then we can go back to stabilizer codes. To be a bit cheeky, a single unencoded qubit is a stabilizer code (with stabilizer group $\{I\}$) but clearly has code states that aren't "uniform".

Comment: Sure but the code space is still spanned by uniform codewords because you can pick $ |0> $ and $ |1> $. Also that trivial code does not have $ d \geq 2 $.

Comment: related papers explicitly demonstrating spin codes corresponding to multiqubit codes with nontrivial distance: https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.08611 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.07023